# While putting files in S3 triggering them takes latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I got this flow over AWS:

> Put file on S3 -> trigger -> lambda function that inserts item to
>   DynamoDB -> see that I actually got new item ove DynamoDB

While I'm uploading few files (about 5-10) to S3, which triggering the lambda call, it takes time to see the expected results inside my DynamoDB.

It seems like there is a queue which being handeled behind the scenes of the S3 trigger. Becuase when i'm uploading few more files, those which didn't seen before are now presented as an item in DynamoDB.

My expected result is to see new Item in DynamoDB by each file(s) upload to S3 in the second it was made.

Is there a way to handle this issue using any configuration ?

Comment: What kind of latency are we taking about? Can you please provide some data how much time (in seconds) it exactly takes? Are you seeing this latency issue only for the first few file uploads? Did you capture the file upload time in log, time when it is processed in lambda and created time stamp in DynamoDB ?

Comment: The latency is when i'm uploading few more files, so only then I can see those which I upload earlier

Comment: usually, it might take few seconds, how much latency we are talking about? And are you using strongly consistent in dynamodb?

Comment: Have you compared the timestamps of the various actions?  Specifically, comparing the Cloudwatch log timestamps (and duration) of the Lambda functions with each other and with the `Last-Modified` timestamp of the object in S3 (which is the creation timestamp)?  If your Lambda function has not fired at all for 10-15 minutes, it will take several seconds for it to fire up -- Lambda is, in a sense, faster under load and a bit sluggish when left idle.  Upload one file, wait for it to fully process, upload another, compare... repeat... report what you see.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above scenario is related to **"Concurrent Execution"** in Lambda as you are trying to upload 5-10 files.

> Every Lambda function is allocated with a fixed amount of specific
>   resources regardless of the memory allocation, and each function is
>   allocated with a fixed amount of code storage per function and per
>   account.

**AWS Lambda Account Limits Per Region = 100 Default Limit**

[Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

[Concurrent Executions - Refer Event Based Sources (e.g. S3)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html)

You can use the following formula to estimate your concurrent Lambda function invocations:

> events (or requests) per second * function duration

For example, consider a Lambda function that processes Amazon S3 events. Suppose that the Lambda function takes on average three seconds and Amazon S3 publishes 10 events per second. Then, you will have 30 concurrent executions of your Lambda function.

**To increase the limit:-**

Refer **"To request a limit increase for concurrent executions"** section in above link.

> AWS may automatically raise the concurrent execution limit on your
>   behalf to enable your function to match the incoming event rate, as in
>   the case of triggering the function from an Amazon S3 bucket.